# js to determine responsive element width

Tags: javascript, function, responsive

I am new to js and have hit a brick wall with altering how I calculate an element width depending on the screen size. I started with only calculating the width by how many of the list items were set to "plan-visible". It works great on a laptop screen, but doesn't break at css media query widths when the screen is smaller. I then had the brilliant idea (haha) of attempting to this directly in the javascript with an if/else statement, which I have little experience with. The result was that it did absolutely nothing. I researched and researched and it looks (to me) like it should work, but I am obviously missing something. I have included the html, the original js that worked for a static element, and then my failed attempt at making it responsive. Thanks!

html:

```
<div id="product-table" class="clear">
    <div class="plan-visible">
      <h3>BALANCE<em>aap</em><img class="image aap" src="http://localhost:1400/images/baap.png"></h3>
        <a class="sbutton aap" href="">Go to AAP</a>         
        <ul>
            <li>Point and click your way through the preparation of your organization’s Affirmative Action plan.<br>&nbsp;</li>         
        </ul> 
    </div>
    <div class="plan-visible">
      <h3>BALANCE<em>trak</em><img class="image trak" src="http://localhost:1400/images/btrak.png"></h3>
        <a class="sbutton trak" href="">Learn More</a>        
        <ul>
            <li>Manage your organization’s hiring process from start to finish.<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;</li>
        </ul>    
    </div>
    <div class="plan-visible">
        <h3>BALANCE<em>hub</em><img class="image hub" src="http://localhost:1400/images/bhub.png"></h3>
        <a class="sbutton hub" href="">Go to HUB</a>
        <ul>
            <li>Access a centralized compliance information center to view, publish, and share information from your BALANCEworks applications.</li>            
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="plan-visible">
        <h3>BALANCE<em>pay</em><img class="image pay" src="http://localhost:1400/images/bpay.png"></h3>
        <a class="sbutton" href="">Go to PAY</a>        
        <ul>
            <li>Conduct detailed compensation analyses, identify potential pay discrimination, and design a compliant pay structure</li>            
        </ul>
    </div>  
</div>
```

original js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var width = 0;
$('.plan-visible').each(function() {
    width += $(this).outerWidth( true );
});
$('#product-table').css('width', width);
});
```

new, broken js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
var mq = window.matchMedia( "(max-width: 500px)" ); 
if (mq.matches) {
  $('#product-table').css('446', width);
} else {
  var width = 0;
  $('.plan-visible').each(function() {
    width += $(this).outerWidth( true );
  });
  $('#product-table').css('width', width);
}
});
```

css:

```
#product-table {
  margin: 100px auto;
    text-align: center;
  .plan-visible {
      font: 12px 'Lucida Sans', 'trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica;
      text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.8);        
      background: #fff;      
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      color: #333;
      padding: 20px; 
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      -moz-border-radius: 5px ;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
      border-radius: 5px ;   }
  .plan-visible:nth-child(1) {width: 180px;}
  .plan-visible:nth-child(2) {width: 180px;}
  .plan-visible:nth-child(3) {width: 180px;}
  .plan-visible:nth-child(4) {width: 180px;}
  .plan-hidden {display: none;}
}


/* --------------- */   

#product-table h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
  color: $mainBlue;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: -20px -20px 50px -20px;
    background-color: $lightGrey;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;    
}

/* product image settings */

#product-table .plan-visible .image {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 15px auto -65px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

#product-table .plan-visible .image.aap {
    border: 3px solid $aap;
}

#product-table .plan-visible .image.trak {
    border: 3px solid $trak;
}

#product-table .plan-visible .image.hub {
    border: 3px solid $hub;
}

#product-table .plan-visible .image.pay {
    border: 3px solid $pay;
}

/* --------------- */

#product-table ul {
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#product-table li {
    border-top: 1px solid $lightGrey;
    padding: 20px 0 10px 0;
}

/* --------------- */

/* product table specific buttons */

.sbutton {
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif;
      padding: 8px 20px;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: $mainBlue; 
    color: white; 
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid $mainBlue;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;

}

.sbutton:hover {
    background-color: #94ae3c;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #94ae3c;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sbutton.aap:hover {
    background-color: #6f2784;
    border: 1px solid #6f2784;
}

.sbutton.trak:hover {
    background-color: #5c89b4;
    border: 1px solid #5c89b4;
}

.sbutton.hub:hover {
    background-color: #b58f2e;
    border: 1px solid #b58f2e;  
}

.sbutton.pay:hover {
    background-color: #94ae3c;
    border: 1px solid #94ae3c;
}
```

Comment: This can and should probably all be done with CSS.  Are you trying to change the width of `.plan-visible` when your resize the browser?

Comment: I am trying to change the width of #product-table. I probably should have included the css, updating that now!

Comment: Are you saying that you tried media queries and they did not work? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZORQPB

Comment: Yep, unfortunately. The width I am setting in the JavaScript is taking priority over any css media queries.

Comment: then don't use javascript?